# Where is the root morpheme in the Modern English word "absent"?

Tags: etymology, morphology

I can't say whether the root morpheme in "absent" is "ab-" or "abs-". (From an etymological point of view, ab- appears to be a negative prefix -- from M.Fr. absent (O.Fr. ausent), from L. absentem (nom. absens), prp. of abesse "be away from, be absent" -- from O.Fr. absence, from L. absentia, noun of state from absentem (nom. absens), prp. of abesse "be away from, be absent," from ab- "away" + esse "to be").

On the one hand, "absent" may be analyzed and compared with "present" (pre-/ ab- sent), but in this case it's clear that we can't consider -s- as a common root for those semantically related words, because it doesn't seem to be the lexical core of these words at all. On the other hand in the case of "abnormal" and "normal" this negative prefix ab- is easily identified.

Comment: What do you mean about considering *-s-* as a common root; don't you mean *-sent*?

Comment: Consider other *-sent* words: *assent*, *consent*, *dissent*. Different Latin roots, but in English that is more or less masked.

Comment: Other words have no clear root meaning in English, e.g. *-mit* in *submit*, *permit*, *commit*, *transmit*. (Just throwing some points of consideration out here :)

Comment: As I see it    abs -ent, -ence, these derivational suffixes (-ent, -ence) are identified  when we do the morphemic analysis of absence, absent or presence, presence

Comment: @subic: I think you could also make an argument that most English speakers don't decompose these words at all.  After all, these words have been lexicalized for a long time.  There are words like *essence* that have no corresponding form, *essent* — you would think if the *-ent/-ence* suffix pair is really "active" that *essent* should be a word.  In any case, not every word with a suffix has to have a root with meaning; see [cranberry morpheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cranberry_morpheme).

Comment: Taking into consideration the fact that the inventory of derivational suffixes in English is limited (Stockwell and Minkova, for example, list 129 affixes, Hay and Baayen - 54 suffixes and 26 prefixes) and the inventory of roots is unlimited (as in any other languages of that kind) it's easier to analyze the morphemic structure of words by taking off derivational suffixes identified by the identity of form and meaning. In case with absent and absence, as for me, the derivational suffixes were separated correctly, weren't they?

Comment: @subic: That's the thing — were they separated correctly, or is it just that there is allomorphy in the stem: *-sent/sence*.  Yes, there is a suffix *-ent* and a corresponding suffix *-ence*, but the transition from /t/ to /s/ is lenition that I think is mandatory before front vowels in Latin; the *-ence* suffix was originally *-ent* + *-ia* which automatically yields *-en[s]ia* with palatalization.  And words that came through French ended up as *-ence* (as opposed to *-ency*) in English. So French kind of masks the obvious *-ia/-ie/y* suffix.

Comment: My point is that any stem that happens to end with *ent* could end up with a corresponding *ence* noun if it took the *-ia* suffix in Latin and both forms passed through French.  So not every *ence/ent* combo needs to be analyzed as being those discrete morphemes.  The morphosemantic problem you point out in your question is one reason why people like Baayen today are abandoning morphemic analysis in favor of amorphous morphology.  (I should probably put these thoughts together into some sort of an answer :)

Comment: O.K. But all these assimilative processes that happened to -ent in Latin were relevant for Latin, not for English. And the position I've taken for analyzing Modern English is based on synchronic approach to the structurally relevant relationships between linguistic elements (morphemes). And all these foreign elements that came into English since Middle English can't get automatically the status of morphemes (meaningful elements) in English - not every latin morpheme can be a morpheme in English, its morphemic status must be justified by some objective criteria.

Comment: Thank you,  Kosmonaut, for your attention to this question :).

Comment: @subic: Yes, that is kind of what I was trying to say.  I just wouldn't be as aggressive as you in saying that all words ending with *ence/ent* would necessarily be analyzed by English speakers as those suffixes. (Though, English *does* show sensitivity to palatalization in Latinate combinations: take a nonce word ending in "t" and add *-ion* or a nonce word ending in "c" and add *-ity*.)  Oh, and one other morphemic possibility is that the stem is *-se-* and there was vowel assimilation, or that the suffixes are really *-nt* and *-nce*.

Comment: But I have serious doubts that people pull out the *pre-* in *presence*.  It does not act like *pre-* at all: even when it is stressed, it is not pronounced [pri]; instead it is [prɛ].  And if *present* isn't pulled apart, who knows if people will then extract *ab-* from *absent*?

Comment: That's why I consider abs- in absent as a root. What about Modern English conscience, where is the root morpheme here? What do you think? To my mind /konʃ/ is the root in consc-(i)ence, because there is a such a word as consc-ious (we don't deal with etymology of course)

Comment: In case with operate and cooperate, co- (variant of con-) will be regarded as a prefix, but in words like conscience, connect the morphemic status of prefix con- is under the question.

Comment: @subic: It could be that *abs-* is a root, or that, say , *absen-* is a root, or even that *absent* is just taken as a whole and there is some deletion/assimilation in getting to *absence*.  Same with *conscience*.  I am personally not operating under a theory where it is *so* important to make sure a line is neatly drawn between root and affix in every case.  *Conscience* came from French and *conscious* came from Latin.  *Conscience* today doesn't semantically relate to *conscious* today in the way one would think. So maybe people parse out affixes from these words, but they might not.

Comment: (By "in the way one would think" I mean *conscience* doesn't mean *consciousness*.)

Comment: Kosmonaut, thank you for your interesting speculations about roots in loanwords. I'd like to be helpful for your scientific investigation as well.

Comment: Good luck! Hope my questions were interesting for you.

Comment: @subic: Questions like yours are why I get a lot out of EL&U.

Comment: let's discuss one more case. This time it must be interesting for you. The question is - Where is the root morpheme in Kosmonaut ( Et. Dict. says: from Russian kosmonavt, from COSMO- + Greek nautēs sailor).  Cosm? (cosm-ic, cosm-ology) Cosmo? cosmo - seems to be a combining form. As for me, there are 2 root morphemes COSM and NAUT (argo-naut, naut-ic-al). What do you think?

Comment: Again, between COSMO and COSM, it is really a matter of your particular theory.  For me, it doesn't really matter.  *Cosmonaut*, *astronaut* and *aeronaut* are all borrowed words.  It is just a small number, so I think new words would be formed by analogy — the construction doesn't seem very productive in general.  I'm not sure that most people make the connection between *-naut* and *nautical* (maybe, but I have doubts).  The *cosm-* part almost certainly does get linked with *cosmic* and *cosmos* on the other hand.

Answer (score 3):

Interesting question with an interesting answer. I understand what @subic is trying to get at. Taken from Dictionary.com, here is the etymology of "absent":

> 1350–1400; Middle English  < Latin absent-  (stem of absēns,  present participle of abesse  to be away ( ab- ab-  + -s-  be ( see is) + -ent- -ent))

@subic, were you wondering over the 's'? Well, I looked up further, and I realised why the 's' was there at all. From Wiktionary:

> From Middle French absent < Old French ausent < Latin absent-, the stem of absens, present participle of abesse (“to be away from”), formed from ab + esse (“to be”).

Note that "abesse" as you said was the original word, but the Latin word is "absent-", whose root is "absens". IT was here, that 's' first got stuck in. Why? I looked up the Latin *absens*, and I got this:

> Present active participle of absum (“be away from, absent”)

So, *absens* came from *absum*, so I looked up *absum*, and I found this:

> From ab (“from”) + sum (“be”).

The 's' originally came from 'sum', and along with all the deriving and everything, remained there, as it was derived from 'absum'. In fact, if you looked up "abesse", you would find that it is actually a derivative of "absum"!

So, the thing that is confusing, is *abesse*, which is actually a :

> present active infinitive of absum

So, I hope that answered your questions.

Comment: Thank you. Am I right to define ABS as a root in Modern English "absent"?

Comment: Yeah, I think so :-)

Comment: I'm sorry but the development of the Latin words isn't entirely as you described. The Latin verb *sum* has several unrelated Proto-Indo-European roots (* h1es-, * bʰuH-, and possibly * h1er-) that (probably) resulted in several more Proto-Latin roots. The hypothetical present participle * sent- comes from * h1es-, and together with ab- (from Latin a/ab/abs) formed *absens, absent-* in Latin. You cannot say that one form of the verb esse or another was the "original" form.

Comment: I beg you pardon, but I am analyzing the roots in Modern English, not in IE or Proto-Germanic. I'm interested in precise identification of roots in the Modern English language.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what the issue is here.

*ab-* indicates *from* or *away*, while *prae-* shortened to *pre-* indicates *before* or *already*.

In *absent* and *present*, *-sent* represents the present participle indicating *being*.

In *abnormal*, *ab-* has a similar indication.  I would accept that *extraordinary* has a similar suggested meaning but is often more positive; that is just usage.

Comment: As a classicist I must support this answer. Apart from the pre-classical-Latin history of these words, this is all the relevant information. Latin *ab-* comes from the Proto-Indo-European root **h2ep(o)-,* "away from". The *s* comes from **h1es-,* "to be". The *e* is a theme vowel. The consonant cluster *-nt-* is used to form the stem of the present participle in many Indo-European languages. In Latin, the nominative singular participle gets *-s,* and *-nts* contracts to *-ns* in Latin. The stem on *-nt* is used in the other cases and in the Romance languages, cf. French *absent.*

Comment: That's all right, but the question is where the root morpheme in Modern English, etymology  is of little help for the synchronic relations of the meaningful elements in a particularly language.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO Not every word will have root 'word' so-to-speak. There are root letters. As in the word absent. ab=prefix -ent=suffix. Root seems 'to be' S which is a picture of DNA. Take the word essence. Esse is the root word however, the ES-SE should give you some indication that this is double SS. Two strands of DNA.

These are letters which are pictures to represent concepts. That is what the alphabet is. Let us not forget this. Take the word interpreter for example. What is the root word? In-t-er-pre-t-er. T and T are the root letters. Everything else is a prefix or suffix. T is relative to the sun at winter solstice.  So yes, absent would have a root letter of S. S begins words like soul, sol, spirit, sense, space, sentient, science, safe, slight, slope, solute and sad (there are more of course).

Absent when taking only as that one word and not with all of our relations we attach to it already when thinking of examples, must be taken into context when trying to figure out what the word all by itself is trying to tell us.

Someone mentioned -mit (submit), which is based off of the root letters MT, which make up Ma'at (which is order), math (definitely related to Ma'at), might, mitigate and so on.

Comment: +1 for "not every word has to have a root" (which I take to mean, not every word is analyzable into pieces). In MSE 'absent' is its own word (despite 'pre-sent'). You can't make new words with 'abs-' or '-sent'.